# If someone doesn't have a head, should he still put on the hand tefillin (with a bracha)?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, tefilin

B"H

There's a known discussion regarding if the hand and head tefillin are separate Mitzvos or the same. Some include each as a separate Mitzvah in the list of Mitzvos, others (I believe) include them together

This has practical applications regarding the question of saying one bracha for both the hand and the head together, or a separate brocho for each

This would also (seemingly?) be the reasoning for the law that [one who is missing a hand still puts on the head tefillin (with a bracha)](https://Putting%20on%20only%20Shel%20Rosh%20or%20Shel%20Yad).

The question is, what would be the law if one is missing a head, would he still be obligated to put on the hand tefillin, or would there be any reason to do so?

Regarding the general reasoning of the hand tefillin before the head tefillin (even though the head one is "on a higher level" (head rules over the heart, so why should it go second to the heart in this case?)) [the Maamer וחזקתה in ספר המאמרים מלוקט,](https://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/mlukat/4/11/index.htm#_ftnref_911) explains the deeper meanings for the head and arm tefillin, then analyzes why were put the arm tefillin before the head:

ו) וממשיך בהמאמר, דזהו מ"ש בשל"ה48 דיעקב הוא תפילין של ראש ויוסף הוא תפילין של יד, כי ע"י תפילין של ראש נעשה החיבור (תפילין מלשון התחברות) דאוא"ס המאציל עם הנאצלים, שממשיך תוספות אור באו"א ובז"א דאצילות, וע"י תפילין של יד שהוא במלכות [כמ"ש49 וקשרתם לאות על ידכה, יד כהה50, דיד כהה היא המלכות] נעשה החיבור דאוא"ס (גם) עם הנבראים. [דזהו מה שתש"ר נק' בשם פאר51, כמו תכשיט שהאדם מתקשט בו52, ותפילין של יד53 הם רק לבוש, כי בי"ע הם לבושים וע"ס דאצילות נק' בשם תיקונין54, דתיקונין הוא כמו תכשיטים55]. וזהו שיעקב הוא תש"ר ויוסף תש"י, כי יעקב הוא בריח התיכון שמבריח ומחבר אוא"ס עם הנאצלים, ויוסף הוא מחבר [בן פורת יוסף56, פורת אותיות תופר57, תופר ומחבר] אוא"ס עם הנבראים.

וצריך להבין, דכיון שבכדי שתהי' המשכה בבי"ע צ"ל תחלה ההמשכה באצילות, למה מקדימין הנחת תש"י לתש"ר. ויש לומר הביאור בזה ע"פ הידוע58 שהמצוות דהקב"ה שנעשים ע"י שישראל מקיימים את המצוות הם נעלים יותר מהמצוות דהקב"ה כמו שהם מצד עצמם. ויש להוסיף, דבמצות תפילין, ענין זה הוא

109
ביותר. דמכיון שתפילין דמארי59 עלמא מה כתיב בהו כו' ומי60 כעמך ישראל גוי אחד בארץ61, דקוב"ה משתבח בשבחייהו דישראל61 – הרי בזה נוגע עוד יותר העבודה דישראל, הנחת תפילין דישראל. ולכן מקדימין הנחת תש"י לתש"ר, כי המעלה דעבודה היא בעיקר בהעבודה דיחודא תתאה (בי"ע)62, ולכן העבודה דיחו"ת מגעת למעלה יותר מהעבודה דיחו"ע (אצילות), וההוספה שנעשית בתפילין דמארי עלמא [המשכת אוא"ס באצילות (תש"ר) ובי"ע (תש"י)] ע"י הנחת תפילין דישראל, היא בעיקר ע"י הנחת תש"י63.

והנה זה שע"י קיום המצוות דישראל מיתוסף עילוי בהמצוות דהקב"ה הוא64, כי ישראל עלו במחשבה65, מחשבה עצמית שלמעלה מכל הגילויים (גם מהגילוי דחפץ חסד66 שהוא השרש והסיבה לכל הגילויים), ולכן ע"י העבודה (קיום המצוות) דישראל מיתוסף עילוי בהמצוות דהקב"ה. ועפ"ז יש לומר עוד טעם על זה שההוספה בתפילין דמארי עלמא היא בעיקר ע"י הנחת תש"י, כי ההמשכה בבי"ע (תש"י) מגעת בהעצם שלמעלה משרש ההשפעה והגילוי (כנ"ל סעיף ה), שבכללות הוא בחינת מחשבה עצמית הנ"ל.

ז) וזהו וחזקת והיית לאיש, דזה שבן י"ג שנה נעשה איש ע"פ טבע, הוא ענין שמצד למעלה, מצד שהקב"ה הטביע הטבע בהבריאה, ומכיון שעיקר המעלה דכל ענין הוא כשהוא בא ע"י עבודת האדם (כנ"ל בארוכה), לכן צ"ל וחזקת והיית לאיש, שיהי' לאיש (גם) ע"י עבודתו. ועפ"ז יש לבאר גם הדיוק דוחזקת והיית לאיש, דאיש מורה על המדות, אף שהמעלה דבן י"ג שנה היא בהמוחין, שיש לו עצם המוחין שלמעלה מענין המדות, כי המעלה דעבודת האדם שמגעת במחשבה העצמית היא בעיקר בהעבודה דהמשכת עצם המוחין (שלמעלה מענין המדות) בהמדות, ע"ד המבואר לעיל בענין יוסף שממשיך גילוי האצילות (שלמעלה משרש הנבראים) בבי"ע.

ויש לקשר כ"ז עם עבודתו של כ"ק מו"ח אדמו"ר, יוסף שבדורנו67, שהמאמר ד"ה וחזקת והיית לאיש נאמר בסיום וחותם חגיגת הבר מצוה שלו, שעבודתו העיקרית היתה יפוצו מעינותיך חוצה, שגם בחוצה הכי תחתון שאין חוצה למטה

110
ממנו68 יומשכו (נוסף על מים שנמשכים מהמעינות, גם) המעינות עצמם. שזו (הפצת המעינות חוצה) היא ההכנה והכלי לאתי בקרוב ממש מר דא מלכא משיחא69

Here is a summary of the concepts related to tefillin in the passage:

- According to the Shla, Yaakov represents the tefillin of the head, connecting the Infinite (Ein Sof) with the emanated realms (the sefirot of Atzilut). Yosef represents the tefillin of the arm, connecting the Infinite with created beings (the worlds of Beri'ah, Yetzirah and Assiyah)
- The tefillin of the head enable the connection (chibur, related to 'attachment') of the Infinite with the emanated beings (the sefirot). This draws down additional light into the sefirot of Atzilut, specifically Abba and Imma.
- The tefillin of the arm connect the Infinite with created beings. This is because the tefillin of the arm correspond to Malchut, the lowest sefirah, which bridges to the created worlds. Malchut is referred to as 'Yad Kehah', the 'dark hand'.
- The tefillin of the head are referred to as 'Tash'R', meaning 'ornament'. They ornament and beautify the sefirot. The tefillin of the arm are a 'garment' for the created beings. The sefirot themselves are referred to as 'tikkunim', which also means 'ornaments'.
- Thus, Yaakov represents Tash'R, connecting the Infinite to the emanated beings, while Yosef represents Tash'Y, connecting the Infinite to created beings. Yosef is described as a 'Poret Yosef', with 'poret' having the same letters as 'tofer' - meaning to connect.
- Though light must first extend through Atzilut for there to be a flow into the created worlds, the passage says that the donning of tefillin of the arm (Tash'Y) precedes that of the tefillin of the head (Tash'R). This is because the mitzvot performed by the Jewish people draw down a higher light than the mitzvot on their own. This is especially true of tefillin, which refer to the Jewish people as God's chosen one, His 'am segulah'. Therefore, the Tash'Y, which corresponds to human action, reaches higher than Tash'R. The increase caused by donning tefillin, the union of Ein Sof in both Atzilut and the created worlds, comes primarily through Tash'Y.
- The passage explains that human action, by transcending all revelations including that of Chesed, reaches the level of God's transcendent Will. Therefore human avodah increases the light in the mitzvot. This is another reason why the increase from tefillin primarily comes through Tash'Y - because it reaches the Essence that transcends the source of all revelation and emanation.

---

---

Based on this it seems that the main thing would be the tefillin of the hand, but it also says that the tefillin of the head itself is the main thing in terms of the revelation of the light. So it's still not clear if one is missing the head - the revelation of light - if he should still draw down the Essence through the hand.

The question of how could someone live without a head, first of all:

Not all questions in the Torah have real practical applications. One time in a Gemara shiur in B"K the Rav was giving two possible ways of explaining the sugya, and someone asked, "what's the practical difference?" And the answer was that if one is mikadeish an isha on the condition that the sugya means one way or the other, is it a valid kiddushin.

Maybe someone actually has a brain, but the section of the head that the tefillin needs to be put on could be either damaged, partially missing chos vishalom, or otherwise inaccessible. In this case the question of what to do about the hand tefillin (if a bracha should be made on it etc or if one is totally pattur) applies at all.

Do we say that maybe the entire purpose of drawing down the Essence (hand) is for the sake of the revelation (head), and thus without the revelation one shouldn't put the hand one on (with a bracha), or maybe that even the essence alone is valuable in it's own right?

Comment: Peliemo almost got kicked of the bais medrash for such a kind of question...first thing that came to mind..

Comment: @sam key word "almost"

Comment: Of course this is a valid question. But it would make more sense to ask it in a case where someone 'somehow' has a head, but for whatever reason they can't put tefillin on their head. Maybe because they don't have a kosher pair of tefillin shel rosh.

Comment: If someone doesn't have a head, even if they are somehow alive, they probably don't have eyes and ears and a mouth, which makes it very hard for them to communicate with others, which makes them a Cheresh which is pattur from all mitzvos, since they are assumed to be mentally incompetent. https://www.bvkkosher.com/deafness-in-halacha

Comment: @kehas chershim are no longer pattur,I know a few who actually go to Chabad regularly and put on tefillin. Look up the deaf Rabbi

Comment: Excuse me, if they are also blind besides for being deaf and mute, it is much harder for them to communicate. There is not much to argue about here. If they don't communicate well, then they are probably pattur. If they somehow do communicate well, then you know that I will agree. Just because you know chershim that put on tefillin, that doesn't mean that they are obligated.

Comment: Another suggested reason why these people are pattur from mitzvos is because it is too hard for them. Communication does not completely change that. See 
the 15th paragraph of this article  https://etzion.org.il/en/holidays/chanuka/regarding-blind-persons-obligation-mitzvot-part-i

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_the_Headless_Chicken

Answer (score 3):

The Rema in [26:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.26.2?lang=bi) brings from the Tur that one who only puts on the shel yad (for whatever reason) should only make one bracha (insinuating that he should still put on the shel yad alone)

> ואם הניח של יד לבד מברך להניח לבד [טור]:

> And if one only puts on the hand tefillin, he should only recite the blessing "...to place" (Tur)

The MB in [26:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.26.3?lang=bi) brings others who disagree and say that both brachos should be made, however he concludes that most hold only one is made:

> (ג) מברך להניח - עיין בפמ"ג שהביא עוד פוסקים דס"ל דאף על של יד לבד נמי מברך שתי ברכות ולהלכה הסכימו האחרונים דאינו מברך על ש"י אלא להניח לבד דבלא"ה הרבה ראשונים ס"ל דאפילו על שתיהן נמי אינו מברך אלא אחת.

> He should only recite the blessing "...to place" - See Pri Megadim who quotes other poskim who hold that even on the hand tefillin alone one should recite both blessings.  However, the Achronim agree that on the hand tefillin alone one should only recite the blessing "...to place", since, even putting that aside, many Rishonim hold that even when putting on both tefillin, one should only recite one blessing.

So logic should follow that someone missing their head, would still have to put on the shel yad with a bracha.

Comment: This is probably the correct answer. But these sources are talking about someone that has a head. Someone that has no head might be pattur. Because the Gemara in Menachos 42b says וקשרתם וכתבתם, כל שישנו בקשירה ישנו בכתיבה, כל שאינו בקשירה אינו בכתיבה. So maybe we can also say  כל שישנו בוקשרתם לאות על ידך ישנו בוהיו לטטפת בין עיניך, כל שאינו בוקשרתם לאות על ידך אינו בוהיו לטטפת בין עיניך. See https://din.org.il/2020/12/21/%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%D7%AA-%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94/

Comment: I'm not convinced that this has anything to do with if shel yad and shel rosh are separate mitzvos or not. Because וכתבתם of mezuzah is definitely a separate mitzvah.                 Also see beginning of 
https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/on-which-arm-to-wear-the-tefillin-in-case-of-paralysis-amputation-or-immobilization-rl/#_ftn3    with footnote 3.